# How to update a postgres jsonb field using eloquent models

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, jsonb

I have the following table in my postgresql database:

```
OOSama:
ID: AUTOINCREMENT BIGINT
NAME: VARCHAR(255)
NANI_WO_SUKI: JSONB
```

The `NANI_WO_SUKI` fields can contain the follwowing JSON:

```
{
  "kodomo":false,
  "dagashi":true,
  "kurosakikun":true
}
```

So I want to be able to update it without using raw SQL query. So I made the following model:

```
namespace App\Model;

class OOSama extends BaseModel
{
  protected $table = "oosama";

  public function setSuki(String $thing, bool $loves)
  {
      //Update JSONB field here

      $this->nano_wo_suki=//Set value here
      return $this;
  }
}
```

So, I can use Eloquent's triggered events on model save as well in order to trigger or update another database tables as well or even renew my caches.

Do you know how I can update a JSONB field on Eloquent without using SQL query?

Comment: Have you tried https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updating-json-columns

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting.

Comment: I will take the latter one.